# Conditional Statements in xsl while parsing XML

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert XML file to CSV using XSL But facing problem while applying conditional statements.
I have following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <User>
        <userid>2000</userid>
        <fruit>
           <FieldValue>
               <Name>Apple</Name>
               <value>500</value>
           </FieldValue>

           <FieldValue>
               <Name>Orange</Name>
               <value>1000</value>
            </FieldValue>

            <FieldValue>
              <Name>Pineapples</Name>
              <value>500</value>
            </FieldValue>
        </fruit>
        <biometric>
            <FieldValue>
              <Name>Weight</Name>
              <value>50lb</value>
            </FieldValue>
        <biometric>
   </User>
</document>
```

I need a output for each user with following constant header format:

```
userid,Apple,Avocardo,Orange,Pineapples,Height,Weight
2000,500,,1000,500,,50lb
```

Please, note that Avocardo and Height are absent in original XML file which are to be assigned as NULL or empty value.
Could someone help to write an xsl for this csv parsing ?

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the solution can be (in 2.0)

```
<xsl:template match="User">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="userid"/>
  <xsl:for-each 
     select="'Apple','Avocardo','Orange','Pineapples','Height','Weight'">
   <xsl:value-of 
     select="concat(',', $this//FieldValue[Name=current()]/value)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```